# Can you bind the selected item in a listbox to a separate object in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, xaml

If I have two objects, one being the list of items, and the other having a property storing the selected item of the other list, is it possible to update the selected item through binding in WPF?

Lets say I have these two data structures:

```
public class MyDataList
{
    public ObservableCollection<Guid> Data { get; set; }
}

public class MyDataStructure
{
    public Guid ChosenItem { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to bind a Listbox to an instance of both objects so that the ChosenItem property gets set by the selected item of the ListBox?

EDIT: To make things a bit clearer, there might be many instances of MyDataStructure, each with a chosen item from MyDataList. The data list is common to all the instances, and I need a way to select an item and store that selection in the MyDataStructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should be able to do this (make sure to declare the local namespace):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyDataStructure x:Key="mds1" />
</Window.Resources>    
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" SelectedValue="{Binding Source={StaticResource mds1} Path=ChosenItem}"/>
```

Comment: Yep that worked. Is it possible to do without using the Static Resource though?

Answer (score 1):

Make this two properties inside a single class(Just to simplify the solution) and make the code ready for property changed events

```
 public class MyDataList : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Guid _choosen;

    public ObservableCollection<Guid> Data { get; set; }

    public Guid ChosenItem {
        get
        {
            return _choosen;
        }
        set 
        {
            _choosen = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ChosenItem"));
        } 
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

create an instance of this class and Bind to the DataContext of the ListBox
Now write the ListBox XAML code as bellow. SelectedValue binding is doing the trick here.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ChosenItem}" x:Name="listBox"/>
```

Comment: Not really possible. I might have several Chosen items in different listboxes, where the items are coming from the same source but the chosen item will be different.

Comment: But the catch here is using SelectedValue Binding. The DataArchitecture can be anyway way as you wanted.